# Oracle Pro*C Bulk Merge of records in C/C++ using host arrays

Tags: c++, c, oracle11g, oracle-pro-c, embedded-sql

Using Oracle Pro*C in C/C++, we can use host arrays for managing bulk inserts into the EMP table as per following example:

```
struct 
{ 
    char ename[3][10]; 
    int eno[3]; 
} emp_rec1; 
struct 
{ 
    int dno[3]; 
} emp_rec2; 

... 
strcpy(emp_rec1.ename[0], "e1"); 
strcpy(emp_rec1.ename[1], "e2"); 
strcpy(emp_rec1.ename[2], "e3"); 
emp_rec1.eno[0] = 1964; emp_rec2.dno[0] = 5; 
emp_rec1.eno[1] = 1974; emp_rec2.dno[1] = 5; 
emp_rec1.eno[2] = 1985; emp_rec2.dno[2] = 5; 

EXEC SQL INSERT INTO emp (ename, eno, dno) 
    VALUES (:emp_rec1, :emp_rec2);
```

Can I do a MERGE using `EXEC SQL MERGE` kind of to try an update first (if ename and eno exist) with dno getting updated, if does not exist then of course insert to do a bulk merge instead of trying to merge one record at a time, e,g, do a select first, of record exists, try an update else apply insert.
Please help with similar example and syntax for bulk merge as embedded SQL in Pro*C.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking at pro*c code that uses the merge command. It does the following.

```
 EXEC SQL
 EXECUTE 
 BEGIN
         MERGE INTO aTable
         USING
         ...
         WHEN MATCHED THEN
             UPDATE SET
         ...
END;
END-EXEC;
```